# Insert object (jquery) delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I allow the user to insert an object, an image, and then i call a function on that object. What seems randomly to me,  sometimes it works and sometimes not, I guess it has to do with the DOM not being updated yet?

```
//add a new image
function add_image(img) {

var objCount = count_objects() + 1;
var objId = 'object_'+objCount;

var myNewImg = jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: objId,
    class: 'object_image invisible',
}).appendTo('#objectbox');

//sätt objektnamnet (användaren kan ändra senare)
$('#'+objId).attr('namn', objId)

//sätt låsta proportioner som standard
$('#'+objId).addClass('lockedAspectRatio')

//lägg till bilden i detta element
var imgInner = jQuery('<img/>', {
    id: objId,
    class: 'object_image_inner',
    src: img,
}).appendTo( '#'+objId );



window.objectCounter++;

prepare_editmode();

//reset the flag and the temporary image field now that image adding is complete
$('#imageGhost').val(null);

//fixa rätt storlek på bilden
setTimeout(function(){
    restoreSize(myNewImg,imgInner);
    $(myNewImg).removeClass('invisible');
}, 1500);

}
```

Because if I manually trigger that last function with a button after a second or so it always works.

```
function restoreSize(myImg,imgInside) { 

if (imgInside == null) {
    console.log("nothing passed");
    var imgInside = $(myImg).find('img');
}
else {
    console.log("passed alright");
}

//remove fixed dimensions on containing div
$(myImg).css("height", 'auto' );
$(myImg).css("width", 'auto' );

//remove the 100% attribute on the image
$(imgInside).css("width", 'auto' );
$(imgInside).css("height", 'auto' );

//get calculated dimensions of div once img original size determines it
var newWidth = $(myImg).css("width");
var newHeight = $(myImg).css("height");

//...and set them firmly.
$(myImg).css("width", newWidth );
$(myImg).css("height", newHeight );

//restore the height/width 100% property to image in case of new resize
$(imgInside).css("width", '100%' );
$(imgInside).css("height", '100%' );    
}
```

I tries timeout zero with same result - sometimes the image has been loaded and sometimes not so it works randomly, with larger images (taking longer time to load in browser) it of course fails more frequently. Right now I have bypassed it with a seconds timeout but that ain't no pretty solution :-/ perhaps I could put a loop on the find('img') that keeps checking for the image and only proceeds once found? But that might stick me in an infinite loop problem at some times?

Comment: Are you calling `restoreSize` immediately after appending the element (like in your code)? Or are those in two separate places?

Comment: I had a similar experience.  Are you testing that against old browsers and getting a hit or miss?  class is a reserved word and should be in quotes, but I think their is a bigger issue here...

Comment: I think you need wait until browser add the element in DOMTree..
You should try a setTimeout(fx, 0);

Comment: I have some unrelated code in between but i don't wait with calling this second function if that is what you're asking. I thought about timeout but how will i know how much time will be foolproof sufficient at all times? I have only tested in Chrome and Firefox, sometimes it works and sometimes not independent of browser.

Comment: For now I am using a 1,5sec timeout to do the trick, but that is in no way a 100% solution, I don't know wherein the problem is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could this work for you?

```
      function add_image(img) {
        var objCount = count_objects() + 1;
        var objId = 'object_' + objCount;

        var myNewImg = jQuery('<div/>', {
           id: objId,
           class: 'object_image invisible'
        }).appendTo('#objectbox');

        $('#' + objId).attr('namn', objId)

        $('#' + objId).addClass('lockedAspectRatio')

        var imgInner = jQuery('<img/>', {
           id: objId,
           'class': 'object_image_inner',
           src: img
        }).load(function () {
           imgInner.appendTo('#' + objId)
           restoreSize(myNewImg, imgInner);
           $(myNewImg).removeClass('invisible');
        });

        window.objectCounter++;

        prepare_editmode();

        //reset the flag and the temporary image field now that image adding is complete
        $('#imageGhost').val(null);
     }
```

and BTW you've duplicate ids for `myNewImg` and `imgInner`

Comment: @Mattias Svensson did you have a look at it?

Comment: Thanks everyone who contributed to this bounty. I picked this answer as it was based on my code, and pointed out my duplicates. But any one of your answers would probably have done the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of querying the DOM immediately after appending, just store a reference to the element, then reference that. Like:

```
var div = jQuery("<div/>", {
    id: objId,
    "class": "object_image"
}).appendTo("#objectbox");
restoreSize(div);
```

Also, I could've sworn you can't set an object's key as `class` since it's a reserved identifier, without quotes...so use `"class": "object_image"`. Also, you had an extra comma after the `class` value...that's a syntax error, at least in IE.

Comment: @MattiasSvensson Well what exactly happens in `restoreSize`?

Comment: Code added to original question

Answer (score 1):

u can use [load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) of jquery. Here is an example with your code:

http://jsfiddle.net/UhUb7/

```
    var images = [
    "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Apple_pie.jpg"
             ]

$(document).ready(function(){
    addImage(images[0]);
});

function addImage(url){
    var holder = $('<div class="object_image invisible">');
    var image = $('<img src="'+url+'" />');
    holder.append(image);
    $("#objectbox").append(holder);

    image.load(function(){
        holder.show('slow');

       // alert(image.css("width"));
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use the reference you already have?

```
var obj = jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: objId,
    class: 'object_image',
}).appendTo('#objectbox');

restoreSize(obj);
```

Maybe it works

**EDIT**:
You can put a timeout 0 to append your function after the browser render...

```
var obj = jQuery('<div/>', {
        id: objId,
        class: 'object_image',
    }).appendTo('#objectbox');

    setTimeout(function(){ restoreSize(obj) }, 0);
```

Comment: I updated as per suggestion using references instead of trying the find() method, same results.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the images width and height until after the images loads. Thats why the setTimeout works for you sometimes.
Use the image.load() call back function to trigger the code you require to be run after the image has loaded.

```
    var imgInner = jQuery('<img/>', {           
       src: img
    }).load(function () {
       jQuery(this).appendTo('#' + objId)
       restoreSize(myNewImg, this);           
       //and so on
    });
```

Comment: Brendon, I think you may need `jQuery(this).appendTo` instead of `this.appendTo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without jquery, just use the es5 mutation observer and a load event

```
(function (global) {
    "use strict";

    if (!("MutationObserver" in global)) {
        global.MutationObserver = global.WebKitMutationObserver || global.MozMutationObserver;
    }

    function loadImage(e) {
        var img = e.target,
            width = img.clientWidth,
            height = img.clientHeight;

        img.removeEventListener('load', loadImage, false);
        alert("Image loaded: width: " + width + " height: " + height);
    }

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
            switch (mutation.type) {
            case 'childList':
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(mutation.target.children, function (child) {
                    if (child.id === "smiley") {
                        child.addEventListener('load', loadImage, false);
                    }
                });

                break;
            default:
            }
        });
    });

    var container = document.getElementById("container");

    observer.observe(container, {
        childList: true,
        characterData: true,
        subtree: true
    });

    container.innerHTML = "<img id='smiley' src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-b1Z0R5ExM9s/TdWbeGQ-wdI/AAAAAAAAAPI/Ft52XTSxs0s/s1600/blue+sky+wallpaper+%25289%2529.jpg'/>";
}(window));
```

A live example is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/gZysL/)

You can read more about [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) at mdn